# How to Cast JObject to type T

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to assign a value to a field of type T and code is as follows,

```
JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(strEventData);
EventData = jobject.SelectToken("ChangeSet").ToObject<Client>();
```

and i get this error because **`EventData`** is of Type **`T`** and the error is

Cannot implicitly conver type Clientto T

this is the struct look like

```
public struct EventDescriptor<T>
{
    public T EventData;
    public long TimeStamp;
    public ChangeType EventType;
```

Comment: show your code that where this `T` comes from?

Comment: @er-mfahhgk added above

Comment: And the above code that throws error is inside generic method or inside normal method? show the method signature?

Comment: inside the normal method

Comment: ohh, you need a generic method that accepts T as class that you specified.

Comment: @er-mfahhgk how to add that?

Comment: ok wait I'll try to give you generic method

Comment: Answer added you can try at your end :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187027/discussion-between-face-turn-and-er-mfahhgk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below generic method to convert your T as actual class like

```
public static T MyGenericMethod<T>(string strEventData) where T : class
{
    JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(strEventData);
    T result = jobject.SelectToken("ChangeSet").ToObject<T>();
    return result;
}
```

And you can use it like

```
var  EventData = MyGenericMethod<Client>(strEventData);
```

**Edit:**

Answer updated with respect to chat made with OP.

```
public struct EventDescriptor<T>
{
    public Guid AggregateId;
    public T EventData;
    public long TimeStamp;
    public ChangeType EventType;
    public int Version;

    public EventDescriptor(Guid id, IEvent eventData)
    {
        AggregateId = id;
        var strEventData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventData, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto });
        EventData = MyGenericMethod(strEventData);
        Version = 1;
        TimeStamp = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
        EventType = (ChangeType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ChangeType), eventData.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First().Name);
    }

    public static T MyGenericMethod(string strEventData)
    {
        JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(strEventData);
        T result = jobject.SelectToken("ChangeSet").ToObject<T>();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting the same errror

Comment: EventData is a type of T